# Oracle query to retrieve first 2 processed records

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Ref    Ref1  Processed     process_date
----------------------------------------------
123    xxxx     Y          23-03-2017 12:10:00
123    zzzz     N          23-03-2017 12:11:10
123    yyyy     Y          23-03-2017 12:11:10
123    wwww     Y          23-03-2017 12:11:11
121    xxxx     Y          23-03-2017 11:10:00
121    yyyy     N          23-03-2017 11:11:00
121    zzzz     Y          23-03-2017 11:11:10
120    xxxx     Y          23-03-2017 11:00:00
```

How to retrieve only 2 processed records in above data based on process date and Ref and there are more than 2 records?

Result should be

```
123    xxxx  Y  23-03-2017 12:10:00
123    yyyy  Y  23-03-2017 12:11:10
121    xxxx  Y  23-03-2017 11:11:00
121    zzzz  Y  23-03-2017 11:11:10
```

**EDIT :**

I want 2 records **only** if there are 2 or more records with same ref

Thanks!

Comment: tried using self join but don't know how to fit process date , always want first 2 processed records for that ref

Comment: Your result shown is not correct . `121    yyyy  Y  23-03-2017 11:11:00` - this record shown in result does not exist in your sample data.

Comment: In the sample data you have two records for the same Ref (123) and the exact same process_date (the second and third row in your table). Why are you choosing the third row, and not the second row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Ref
    ,Ref1
    ,Processed
    ,process_date
FROM (
    SELECT t.*
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ref ORDER BY process_date
            ) rn
        ,COUNT(Ref) OVER (PARTITION BY ref) ct
    FROM yourtable t
    WHERE Processed = 'Y'
    )
WHERE rn IN (
        1
        ,2
        )
    AND ct >= 2
ORDER BY REF DESC
    ,process_date;
```

**EDIT** : added count check to restrict record counts > 2

Comment: Thanks ,it will return record even if there is single record in table  , I want 2 records only if there are 2 or more records with same ref

Comment: Your result shown in the question is not correct . `121 yyyy Y 23-03-2017 11:11:00 - this record` shown in result does not exist in your sample data

Comment: Check now . I have modified the answer.

Comment: you are master Kaushik ,thanks .is there anyway improve the performance of the query

Comment: Why do you have the condition `where processed = 'Y'`? There is no such condition in the OP's question.

Comment: @mathguy : Op want's only 2 processed records to be considered.processed='N' does not count as processed.

Comment: Oh - I see and it makes sense. Only question to the OP then - in the final clarification, he probably meant "only if there are 2 or more PROCESSED records with same ref."